# Can I copy grease pencil from UV/Image Editor to 3D View?

Tags: grease-pencil

Perhaps there is another easy workflow for this. Just trying to get relative measurements for something in the UV/Image Editor by drawing a few lines with the grease pencil. Then I want to copy the strokes to the 3D View and then rotate (2D) and scale them as needed as a guide to designing objects.

I know I can load images into the 3D View background or load images into a plane in the 3D view, trace things with grease pencil, convert grease pencil to geometry, etc... But for my workflow it would be much more convenient to be able to quickly transfer grease pencil strokes (as strokes or geometry) between views.  It would be nice if this was generally available between all views.